# Hide and show product list on basis of multiple categories in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

```
<div class="content" data-category="shoes" data-price="1000" data-brand="Andrew">shoe1</div><br />
<div class="content" data-category="shirts" data-price="1200" data-brand="Sunbaby">shirt1</div><br />

<div class="content" data-category="shoes" data-price="2000" data-brand="Andrew">shoe2</div><br />
<div class="content" data-category="shoes" data-price="800" data-brand="Andrew">shoe3</div><br />
<div class="content" data-category="shirts" data-price="1300" data-brand="Sunbaby">shirt2</div><br />
<div class="content" data-category="shirts" data-price="800" data-brand="Sunbaby">shirt3</div><br />

<input type="checkbox" class="category" category="shoes" id="shoes">shoes
<input type="checkbox" class="category" category="shirts" id="shirts">shirts
<input type="radio" name="range" value="0-9000" checked>All
<input type="radio" name="range" value="0-999">0-1000
<input type="radio" name="range" value="1000-2000">1000-2000
```

Basically if you select a category from checkbox lets say shoes, then divs only with shoes should get displayed. Then if you filter the results with price, some starting and ending limit, it should show shoes category divs falling in that specific range, Not out of that range.
And in between if you select brand checkbox also.then it should match for all the three checkboxes that is from category and brand and price range

For example:- we selected shoes checkbox, it should show shoe divs; then if we select range as 1000-2000, then it should show shoe1 and shoe2 and not shoe3.

if u select shoe category and then if you select brand checkbox as well.it should filter out on both checkbox basis,and then it should look for price range and match the results,filter the divs.

Please help on this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input.category").prop("checked", true).change(function (e) {
    $("input[name=range]:checked").trigger("change");
});
$("input.brand").prop("checked", true).change(function (e1) {
    $("input[name=range]:checked").trigger("change");
});

$("input[name=range]").change(function (e) {
    var toggle = this.checked;
    var range = this.value.split('-');
    var rangeFrom = parseInt(range[0]);
    var rangeTo = parseInt(range[1]);
    $(".content[data-price]").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var categoryActive = $("#" + $this.data("category")).prop("checked");
        var brandActive = $("#" + $this.data("brand")).prop("checked");
        var price = parseFloat($this.data('price'));
        $this.toggle(price >= rangeFrom && price <= rangeTo && categoryActive);
      $this.toggle(price >= rangeFrom && price <= rangeTo && $("#" + $this.data("brand")).prop("checked"));
    });
});

</script>
```

i tried this script with my one buddy's  help.
Thanks and Google if You can help on this

Comment: So, what have you tried? as far as i know SO is not the place where people code for you on demand. Basically what you want is the entire sorting logic for some sort of online shopping site..  http://www.google.com might help you get started.

Comment: please have a look at script and please help on this

Comment: This is a very fragile way to go about this and should not be implemented in client-side JavaScript.

Comment: i have written the javascript code also.please correct my code please....

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist is totally wrong about implementing this server-side. This is can be done perfectly client-side and there are several libraries to do it.

Comment: @ rafaelcastrocouto-please correct my code sir..

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto By all means, implement an entire shopping cart with no database in client-side JavaScript. Just don't hire me on your phone support staff.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist Don't worry ... I won't hire you ... user I'm working on it!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
$("#shoes").click(function (e) {
 $('.content[data-category=shoes]').toggle();
});
```

Comment: no this will not solve the purpose for me,because i m looking for three combined filters,not the one @user3473274.Thanks

Comment: you are very lazy ! you only want the complete code. learn to code or hire a real developer !

Comment: Thanks @user3473274,you need coding ability,thing u told i implemented years ago.so dont even try to give advice to people because ur advices are very useless like ur coding.....

Answer (score 0):

#### [Solution](http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/rbxht/)

HTML

```
<form id="filter">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="brand" 
           value="Andrew" 
           checked>Andrew
    </input>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="brand" 
           value="Sunbaby" 
           checked>Sunbaby
    </input>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="brand" 
           value="Nike" 
           checked>Nike
    </input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="category" 
           value="shoes" 
           checked>Shoes
    </input>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="category" 
           value="shirts" 
           checked>
      Shirts
    </input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" 
           name="price" 
           value="0-9000"         
           checked>All
    </input>
    <input type="radio" 
           name="price" 
           value="0-999">0-1000
    </input>
    <input type="radio" 
           name="price" 
           value="1000-2000">1000-2000
    </input>
  <div> 
</form>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

JS/JQUERY

```
var filterContentForm = function(content, form){  
  var filter = function() {  
    var checkBoxGroups = {},
        radioGroups = {};
    var addRadioGroup = function(name){
      radioGroups[name] = {      
        el: $('input[name='+name+']:checked')
      };
      var n = radioGroups[name];
      n.el
      .each(function(){
        n.range = $(this).val().split('-');
        n.from = Number(n.range[0]);
        n.to = Number(n.range[1]);      
      });
    };      
    $('#filter input[type=radio]')
    .each(function(){
      addRadioGroup($(this).attr('name'));
    });      
    var addCheckBoxGroup = function(name){
      checkBoxGroups[name] = {
        el: $('input[name='+name+']:checked'),      
        ch: []
      };
      var n = checkBoxGroups[name];
      n.el.each(function(){
        n.ch.push($(this).val());
      });
    };
    $('#filter input[type=checkbox]')
    .each(function(){
      addCheckBoxGroup($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    var contents = $(content), all = 0;
    contents.removeClass('hidden')
    .each(function(){
      var $this = $(this),
          price = $this.data('price');
      for(var c in radioGroups){ 
        var n = radioGroups[c],
            d = Number($this.data(c));
        if(d < n.from || d > n.to){
          $this.addClass('hidden');
          all++;
          return;
        }
      }    
      var show = 0, i;
      for(var c in checkBoxGroups){   
        var n = checkBoxGroups[c], 
            d = $this.data(c);      
        for(i = 0; i < n.ch.length; i++){        
          if(d === n.ch[i]) {
            show++; break;
          }
        } 
      }
      var l = Object.keys(checkBoxGroups).length;
      if(show < l) {
        $this.addClass('hidden');
        all++;
      }
    });
    if(all > contents.length - 1) 
      contents.removeClass('hidden');
  };
  $(form+' input').change(filter);
  filter();
};
filterContentForm('.content', '#filter');
```

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto-Sorry,but i m not able to see it working and we need to filter with three data attributes i.e.brand,category and price but i m able to see category and price only not the brand.Can u please update and thanks....

Comment: did it! and if you need more checkboxes or radios just add the with the proper functions `addCheckBoxGroup` and `addRadioGroup`

Comment: `addCheckBoxGroup` and `addRadioGroup` no longer needed ... just add  checkboxes or radios input elements to the form and they will work like magic!

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto-Thanks man,its working very good.I tried of keeping all the checkboxes unchecked at start,but was unable to make it working with unchecked boxes ,if u check one checkbox one by one.Like initially it was displaying everything with checkboxes unchecked.then we checked andre,it showed the results for andrew.and then we checked sunbaby and we should get results for andrew and sunbaby and so on..Please guide sir..

Comment: If all checkboxes are unchecked then nothing will be displayed ... is that really what you want? Anyway ... I updated so it works even like that!

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto-no sir.i wanted if all are unchecked then everything should be displayed.

Comment: there you go... is that it?

Comment: can we keep on start,all checkboxes unchecked and displaying all records.and displaying records which ever checkboxes are checked.i tried it butsomewhat messed.PLease help brother on this..

Comment: dude go for a library ... can't you see this will never end?